# Possible to get HTTP response headers with nodejs and puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

[image]

Hi there,

is there any possible way to get the server information like the above by using **nodejs** and **puppeteer**?

many thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These are the response headers, which you can get with [response.headers()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#responseheaders):

```js
const response = await page.goto(url);
const headers = response.headers();
console.log(headers);
```